# Calling the same function over multiple argurment in r?

Tags: r

Suppose I have three matrices:

```
Mat1 = matrix(0,4,4)
Mat2 = matrix(0,4,4)
Mat3 = matrix(0,4,4)
```

Then suppose that I need to create numbers of matrix is very difficult to do that manually. Also, I want to make these function as a low triangle matrix using `low.tri(Mat1)`, so is there any way to do that easly.

I search `lapply` families but could not find the answer for my question.

Comment: And to create a large number of these matrices, try:  `lapply(1:_number_of_matrixes_you_want_, function(x) matrix(0, 4,4)) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lapply` is used on lists. First, you insert all your matrices in a `list`. `lower.tri` is a logical function. If you want to get a lower triangle,  you should create a function similar to `f` below. Then you can use `lapply` like so:

```
Mat1 = matrix(0,4,4)
Mat2 = matrix(0,4,4)
Mat3 = matrix(0,4,4)  
l <- list(Mat1,Mat2,Mat3)  

f <- function(m) {
  m[lower.tri(m)] <- 1
  m
}

lapply(l,f)

[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0
[3,]    1    1    0    0
[4,]    1    1    1    0

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0
[3,]    1    1    0    0
[4,]    1    1    1    0

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0
[3,]    1    1    0    0
[4,]    1    1    1    0
```